# Where is the Pinching/Squeeze theorem in Spivak Calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question

So I got Spivak Calculus 3. Edition. I'm starting it now but I want to know if there is the squeeze theorem clearly explained in the book, as I can't find it in the Appendix(pinching theorem, squeezing theorem, sandwich theorem, can't find any of these).

Thanks

Comment: I think is in one exercise. Yeah, chapter 5 ex. 13

Comment: @JoseAntonio But is there anywhere in the book where he explains the Squeeze theorem? I need to understand this first.

Comment: I don't remember it, but there is a really nice explanation of the squeeze theorem in Apostol's book (honestly I prefer the way in which Apostol present the topics but the exercises in Spivak are better, so is a good idea to have both because  they complement each other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the third edition, but in the second one the squeeze theorem is an exercise in Chapter 5. The point (not explicitly made in the book) is that when you really understand the definition of limit (and Spivak puts a lot of work into this in that chapter), you don't really need the squeeze theorem as a theorem, but it is just a natural tool to be used.

Comment: Aha! Looks like I'll get on it then. I hope it becomes natural at some point. First year of uni is hard.

Comment: It will. Still, you might want to mix Spivak with other sources too. I personally feel that Spivak is as clear as can be, but I know for certain that not everybody feels that way.

Comment: It's way better than Stewart. The first chapter in Spivak is a bit abstract but it makes complete sense when he explains how he proves the stuff. This level of abstraction is not even introduced in Stewart and in my opinion it's a must. Spivak is amazing. I guess I should get Apostol 2Ed. I got the first but the second is updated and probably would help.

Comment: I completely agree.